# add running videos in a scrollView

Tags: iphone, video, uiscrollview

I have created a `scrollView` and need to add some running videos to it.
I did the following thing:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    NSURL *fileUrl1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AUDI_anti_crevaison_1" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    NSURL *fileUrl2 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"AUDI_Utilisation_de_la_roue_de_secours_2" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    videoPlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileUrl1];
    videoPlayer2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileUrl2];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:videoPlayer1.view];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width *2, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView release];
```

First of all, it seems this line: `[self.scrollView addSubview:videoPlayer1]` is broken, I cannot add `MPMoviePlayer` to a `UIView`.
And second how can I set the frame for each video...the `xOrigin` and `yOrigin`?

I would appreciate a complete code with adding `.mp4` files to a `UIScrollView` cause I cannot seem to make it work.

Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

- You should read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) first.
- You're trying to add a controller instead of a view that's why it
  doesn't work. I see that you have Android experience - it's like the difference between activity and view on android
- If you still can't figure it out there's a lot of code for adding videos to views on the web, just search it. Don't see it necessary to add here such a generic code.

Comment: Please give me a good link, if there are so many.It will take you less than one minut!thank you:)

Comment: [self.scrollView addSubview:videoPlayer1.view]; view.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h); where x, y, w, h set the position and size of your video view in the scrollview

Comment: Don't know why but I cannot see any video in the scrollView!

Comment: Do the videos work on your device? put them on a web server and test them via a browser first. If yes, try to play one of them after you add it to the scrollview so the video can load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4267/discussion-between-george-and-alin)

Comment: Well, with this code I have no error, but there is also no video shown!My screen is empty, no video!